# Hibernate Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I´m having trouble with Hibernate.

I´m having this exception

`Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

I´m trying to show the date from a database, one of my column is a char, that in my class have a `Enum`

```
public enum Status {

    CADASTRADA('C', "Cadastrada"),
    APROVADA('A', "Aprovada"),
    LIBERADA('L', "Liberada"),
    BLOQUEADA('B', "Bloqueada");

    public char index;
    public String descricao;

    private Status(char index, String descricao) {
        this.index = index;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public static Status valueOf(char index) {
        for (Status status : Status.values()) {
            if (status.equals(index)) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return this.descricao;
    }

    public char getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

}
```

`

I create one `TypeClass` to convert

`public class FilialStatusType extends TypeHibernate {
    public static final String TYPE = "filialStatusType";

```
@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor sessionImpl, Object obj)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    String index = rs.getString(names[0]);

    return StringUtil.isStringNullOrEmpty(index) ? null : Filial.Status.valueOf(index.charAt(0));
}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement ps, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    Filial.Status status = (Filial.Status) value;

    if (NullUtil.isNull(status)) {
        ps.setNull(index, CharacterType.INSTANCE.sqlType());
    } else {
        ps.setString(index, String.valueOf(status.index));
    }
}

@Override
public Class<Filial.Status> returnedClass() {
    return Filial.Status.class;
}
```

}
`

So can someome help me?

Comment: What line or method does it throw this exception?  Is this all the code?  Is there anything in your database?  It seems it finds no rows in your database.

Comment: Yes, there is date in my database, the exception is throw in `Type Class`

Comment: At which method?  And which line?

Comment: `nullSafeGet` 

`return StringUtil.isStringNullOrEmpty(index) ? null : Filial.Status.valueOf(index.charAt(0));`

I´m trying only to see my database but i t showing sql `update`

Comment: It may have something to do with how you're comparing:  if (status.equals(index))

Comment: this is the coeewxr answer...

i´m not comparing the values, i did wrong but now it´s right

Comment: Awesome.  Just posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have something to do with how you're comparing:

```
if (status.equals(index))
```

I don't think you can compare a `enum` and a `char` like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a cuple of things that may cause this:

- A trigger/rule/plsql may deny or refuse your change
- You have no right
- Another user has already did this operation
- some databases supports read-only-connections.

many many more.

if this happens often, you should use @version fields. to enver the entitys.